# How to set some field in model as readonly when a condition is met?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, forms, readonly

I have models like this:

```
class Person
  has_many :phones
  ...
end

class Phone
  belongs_to :person
end
```

I want to forbid changing phones associated to person when some condition is met. Forbidden field is set to `disabled` in html form. When I added a custom validation to check it, it caused save error even when phone doesn't change. I think it is because a hash with attributes is passed to

```
@person.update_attributes(params[:person])
```

and there is some data with phone number (because form include fields for phone). How to update only attributes that changed? Or how to create validation that ignore saves when a field isn't changing? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to use the

```
changed  # => []
changed? # => true|false
changes  # => {}
```

methods that are provided.

The `changed` method will return an array of changed attributes which you might be able to do an `include?(...)` against to build the functionality you are looking for.

Maybe something like

```
validate :check_for_changes

def check_for_changes
  errors.add_to_base("Field is not changed") unless changed.include?("field")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate
  errors.add :phone_number, "can't be updated" if phone_number_changed?
end
```

-- don't know if this works with associations though

Other way would be to override update_attributes, find values that haven't changed and remove them from params hash and finally call original update_attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use before_create, before_save callbacks in model to restrict create/update/save/delete or virtually any such operation. I think hooking up observers to decide whether you want to restrict the create or allow; would be a good approach. Following is a short example.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

   #These callbacks are run every time a save/create is done.
   before_save :ensure_my_condition_is_met
   before_create :some_other_condition_check


   protected
   def some_other_condition_check
     #checks here
   end

   def ensure_my_condition_is_met
     # checks here
   end
end
```

More information for callbacks can be obtained here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Problem with callbacks is that it doesn't show errors even when I add them to error.add_to_base